# How to replace triple backslash with method replace JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, replace, str-replace

I have a function for replacing strings

```
function replaceLetters(str) {
    return str.replace('a\\\a', "!")
}
replaceLetters('a\a a\\a a\\\a')
```

As a result I get string like "aa ! a\a" but I need string like "a\a a\a !"

Can you please help me with this task?

Comment: Your input does not have triple literal backslashes - two backslashes together result in a single literal backslash, and a backslash before a non-escape character gets discarded by the parser.

Comment: If you want to have *triple* backslash, then you need a string literal with *six* backslashes: `"\\\\\\"` produces three bacckslashes because each needs to be escaped.

Comment: @CertainPerformance ok, I understood this,
and what can you advise me? my main task is to get '!' instead of  'a\\\a' 

when I use six backslashes I get "aa a\a a\a"